# SimpleJdbcCall create a lot of connections in a pool in Spring Data and Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using Spring Boot and Spring Data (`jbdctemplate`, `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`) to develop a web service and a pool of connections.

Like `JdbcTemplate` and `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` open and close the connection in each one of the lines in the pool automatically it is great (the pool only is user when the system does an query). On the other hand, when I use the `SimpleJdbcCall` to call an stored procedure I have to use the word `new`:

```
objSimpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(this.objJdbcTemplate.getDataSource()).withSchemaName(strSchema).withProcedureName(strProcedmiento);
```

Because of this the system generates one connection in each request (There are not closed even when the `objSimpleJdbcCall`  variable in the method is killed when it terminates) and the pool begins to increase connections.

Does someone know how to close the connection in the `SimpleJdbcCall`?  or how to use a stored procedure of other way without using the word `new.`

Comment: a) You should pass the whole JdbcTemplate to the `SimpleJdbcCall` constructor - if you pass the datasource, then it will be wrapped in a new JdbcTemplate again b) Why do you think that SimpleJdbcCall doesn't close the connection?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Erwin. I will answer you as you wrote it.
A) The true I had not seen the constructor with `jdbctemplate`, I only saw it with `DataSource`. But will there be any difference? Tomorrow I will try it.
B) We are using As400 and the System i Navigator software, wich helped us to see the number of connections in the data base. which increased when `SimpleJdbcCall` was called and the connections number persisted even after ending the procedure.

Comment: As i see `SimpleJdbcCall` use `JdbcTemplate` and when i check execute method, it is closing automatically within `finally`. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java

Comment: I have done test with `JdbcTemplate` to the `SimpleJdbcCall` constructor. but i do see improvement. The system continues leaving open connections in the pool.
When I only use `jdbcTemplate` it does not happen, The template open an break free the connection pool line automatically. I believe the problem is in 'SimpleJdbcCall ' because i always create a new object `new SimpleJdbcCall`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `jdbcTemplateObject.getDataSource().getConnection()` to get connection, please don't use this. Commenting this line before calling new `SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplateObject).withProcedureName()` solved connections leakage problem.